# Order of writing variables at the top left of a K-Map

Tags: karnaugh-map

[Beginner here]

I was studying from AAC and I've reached [till here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-8/minterm-maxterm-solution/). On this page, they've this example:

[image: Example question with solution]

My confusion is NOT in how to make pairs, quads or octets or how to fill gray codes. I'm good at that. **My only confusion is:**

> How do they decide - in the top-left square of the map - whether CD comes to the right of the diagonal or AB does?

Like in the above example, I put AB to the right of the diagonal and got this answer instead: $$(A+\bar{B}+C)\cdot(A+\bar{B}+D)\cdot(\bar{A}+B)$$ which happens to be the same answer with A,C and B,D swapped. But it's still a drastic change in the answer.

Hence, my question:

> How do they decide - in the top-left square of the map - whether CD comes to the right of the diagonal or AB does?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how you choose to label your K-map. If you are consistent with how you use the mapping, that is, don't change the axis labels between putting your terms in and reading your terms out, then you'll get the same answer.

The K-map is merely a 2D representation (which is easy to see and manipulate) of a higher dimensional space, in this case 4 dimensions (which I personally cannot visualise as easily). The labels have no meaning in themselves, they are merely book-keeping, as long as their use is consistent.

Make sure you are comparing like with like. There is no unique solution to a reduction like this, though there are 4 unique combinations of 0/1 minterm/maxterm, and several other unique 'min this' or 'min that' versions.

As the map is non-symmetric about the diagonal, and as you say you've reached a solution that's a diagonal flip different from the book, it sounds like, without the need for me to work through your example in detail, that you've managed to slip up somewhere in your placement or readout of terms.

Comment: I understood your logic about the 4D thing.

"you've managed to slip up somewhere in your placement or readout of terms." Well I've double checked but the book does not mention any specific rule whether AB is to the left or right of the diagonal of the top-left cell :/

Comment: @GaurangTandon That's the point, it doesn't matter whether AB goes above or below, you will get the same answer. If you don't, you're doing something wrong. I am rubbish at transforming complicated equations, because I always miss a minus sign somewhere, every time. Do a simpler example, perhaps with just two maxterms (not symmetrical), and work through with different labels on your K-map.